# Return previous formula result if condition met

Tags: crystal-reports

I started with what seemed to be a simple task, however after trying numerous methods and researching online, I am at a stand still.

My data, after sorting, is structured as:

```
x  y  
x  z  
x  y  
x   
x   
x   
a  b
```

I wish to have the 2nd column field shown in every row of Col3, `IF Col1 = Prevous(Col1)`.

```
If Col1 <> Previous(Col1) then return Col2.
```

Assuming the formula name is EPS
I've tried:

```
If Col1 = Previous(Col1)  
Then Previous(Col2)  
Else Col2
```

(Resulted in blanks and Z's)

```
If Col1 = Previous(Col1)  
Then Previous(EPS)  
Else Col2
```

(Resulted in formula error, as it cannot refer to itself)

Ideally I would create a third column, hide the second for an end result like:

```
x  y  
x  y   
x  y  
x  y  
x  y  
x  y  
a  b
```

instead, based on the first formula that I tried I get:

```
x  y  
x  y  
x  z  
x  y  
x  
x  
a  b
```

Comment: why can't you manipulate data from the back-end or `sql`?

Comment: I can't because I am only given access to a CSV output file from the database. Which is extremely annoying, given these types of situations. I ended up just writing a VBS script to modify the file how I wanted prior to it being read in Crystal.

Comment: maybe best to dump it in a temporary working table and formulate the query from there. that would be alot easier